# EXTJS MVC Tree Panel

Tags: extjs, treeview, extjs4, extjs-mvc

Am trying to have a tree when a button is clicked. Basically this view has a toolbar in the top, and i want the tree to be displayed below the toolbar. Firstly, am confused what xtype should i use, whether its

```
xtype : 'treepanel'
```

or its

```
xtype : 'treeview'.
```

Here is the code for my tree

```
Ext.define('Campus.view.Hierarchy', {
    alias: 'widget.hierarchy',
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

    initComponent: function () {
        var config = {
            xtype: 'panel',
            border: false,
            autoScroll: true,
            baseCls: 'topMenu',

            dockedItems: [{
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                border: false,
                dock: 'top',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: LANG.BTADDREG,
                    iconCls: 'icon-add-tb',
                    cls: 'tip-btn',
                    iconAlign: 'right',
                    action: 'addRegion',
                    id: 'ADDREGION'
                }],
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'treepanel',
                    title: '',
                    border: false,
                    enableDD: true,
                    viewConfig: {
                        enableDD: true,
                        plugins: {
                            ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop'
                        }
                    },
                    collapsible: false,
                    useArrows: true,
                    rootVisible: false,
                    store: 'HierarchyTree',



                    multiSelect: false,
                    singleExpand: false,
                    id: 'TREE'

                }]
                var holder = Ext.getCmp('center');
                holder.remove(0);
                holder.add(Ext.apply(config));
            }
```

Am defining the store inside the tree because,defining the tree store in the app/store folder, shows error as follows:

```
me.store.getRootNode is not a function
node: me.store.getRootNode()
```

/Model

```
Ext.define('App.model.HierarchyTree', {
extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
fields : ['Title', 'ID', 'LevelID', 'ParentID']
});
```

/Store

```
Ext.define('App.store.HierarchyTree', {
extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
model : 'Campus.model.HierarchyTree',
storeID : 'HierarchyTree',

proxy : {
    type : 'ajax',
    url : 'data/Locations.aspx',
    reader : {
        type : 'json',
        root : 'Rows'
    },
    actionMethods : {
        create : 'POST',
        read : 'POST'
    },
    extraParams : {
        mode : 'HIERARCHYFULLLIST'

    }
},
autoLoad : true
```

});

Also, when i use `xtype :'treepanel'`, its just showing a horizontal scrollbar, and nothing else.
And when i use `xtype: 'treeview'`, its showing

```
me.panel is undefined
treeStore = me.panel.getStore();
```

Could anyone please tell me what mistake am i doing

EDIT

The config is applied to Ext.getCmp('center') because the application is divided into three sections, and so whenever we display a view, we get hold of the center region of the application, and then display it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has some errors. you have two 'items' in the panel config, the first one should be 'tbar'.

Another error is how you add the store, you should just add the class `store : 'HierarchyTree'` or to create the store `store: Ext.create('App.store.HierarchyTree',{})`.

And you should use treepanel since treeview is just the view used by the treepanel.
Add this fixes and see if it will work or if not post the new issues. Hope it helps.

**EDIT**

Ok so another thing, [initComponent](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-method-initComponent) function **must** contain the call to the parent function.

```
this.callParent(); // at the end of the initComponent function.
```

And I still have some questions why do you apply  the config to an item you get with ext.getCmp, isn't the config for the 'Campus.view.Hierarchy' object ?
If so you should apply directly to 'this' object.

```
Ext.apply(this,config);
this.callParent();
```

As it is now, it is not applying the config since apply takes two arguments the destination object and the config object.

**EDIT**
On the issue with the config, you cannot apply the config to the center panel like that, because it's not rendered. 
So rather than doing that you should add the config to the current panel, and add the curent panel to the viewport, which i guess it has layout border.
This shoud be the init component function:

```
config = {
...}
Ext.apply(this,config);
this.callParent();
```

And the panel which contains the center region should have the panel as an item.

```
 ...some viewport...
   layout:'border',
   items: [
        { 
           xtype:'hierarchy',
           region: 'center'
        }
   ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer nscrob. If i change it to treeview, it has an error TypeError: me.store.getRootNode is not a function. node: me.store.getRootNode()   Also, since the requirement is to have a toolbar above the tree, am having two 'items'. And the toolbar has buttons, which again becomes an items array. So, how do i change this? Sorry, if this is a silly question, but am new to MVC

Comment: I have edited my code, and made the toolbar as a docked item. Also, now am not getting any error, but the tree is not getting loaded. When i open the page containing the tree i can see loads of extjs files loaded from /resources/ext/ folder. But, store for tree is not getting loaded

Comment: have you changed the way you add the store to the config? It seems you still create a default with no config,except for the proxy.

Comment: Yup, have changed to  store : 'HierarchyTree', am not getting any error but the tree is not loading and am not able to see any call to the server

Comment: can you post where are you using the config object, either where the panel is added or if you use it in an initComponent function.

Comment: edited my code:) and am getting an error : me.store.getRootNode is not a function

Comment: Am sorry nscrob, but its showing same error:( and have edited the question for the Ext.getCmp()part.

Comment: haha, I missed probably the most important thing :), you have to use 'Ext.data.TreeStore' not the 'Ext.data.Store'.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you nscrob. You are amazing:) For a beginner, you are just so patient to help. 
Ok, now the store is loading and am able to see the response

```
{"text":"Asia Pacific","id":"537","level":"1", "expanded": 
false,"singleClickExpand":true,"children":[{"text":"Japan", "cls":"xtreenode-Level2-
Indent", "id":"538", "hl1":"537","level":"2","singleClickExpand":true, "expanded": false,
"children":[{}]
```

But for some reason, the tree is not displaying. AM working on that. And when i go through the html in the firebug window, its showing the same div id for the tree is overlapping with the docked menu and its like a horizonatal scrollbar. So, am just figuring, where the mistake lies

Comment: Well you have no dimensions, or layout for the panel containing the tree, so you can either set specific dimensions using height and width in the config, or add la layout, for example layout:'fit' to the parent panel 'hierarchy' so the treepanel will fit to the parent panel dimensions.